Bayesian A/B Testing
I've been reading a lot about A/B testing and I understand the basic frequentist methods. I'm having a hard time with the Bayesian approach and was wondering if i could get an explanation of exactly how the Bayesian testing works and why it is favorable. I'm looking for a mathematical explanation.

An A/B test is a particular kind of experimental design but more than one kind of thing can be the subject of that sort of design. Are you just looking at a two sample comparison of count proportions (e.g. CTR) or a comparison of means (such as revenue, for example)? Or both? Or more possibilities than just those two comparisons?

"why it is favorable" - are you sure it is? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/632935/why-do-we-use-hypothesis-tests-instead-of-just-letting-people-do-bayesian-update/633027#633027

@Glen_b both and more possibilities

Which ones did you want? Coverage of every plausible thing that could be subject to that design could be very long indeed.
